# python list looping technique syntax

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am reading an [article](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark) about python removing duplicate element in a list.
there is a function defined as:

```
def f8(seq): # Dave Kirby
    # Order preserving
    seen = set()
    return [x for x in seq if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)]
```

However, i don't really understand the syntax for 
**[x for x in seq if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)]**

what is this syntax ? how do I read it?

thank you.

Comment: This is a *list comprehension*. If you Google the term, there are plenty of tutorials around, e.g. http://carlgroner.me/Python/2011/11/09/An-Introduction-to-List-Comprehensions-in-Python.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly list comprehensions are usually easy to read, here is a simple example:

```
[x for x in seq if x != 2]
```

translates to:

```
result = []
for x in seq:
    if x != 2:
        result.append(x)
```

The reason why you can't read this code is because it is not readable and hacky code as I stated [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17016257/1219006):

```
def f8(seq):
    seen = set()
    return [x for x in seq if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)]
```

translates to:

```
def f8(seq):
    seen = set()
    result = []
    for x in seq:
        if x not in seen and not seen.add(x): # not seen.add(...) always True
            result.append(x)
```

and relies on the fact that `set.add` is an in-place method that always returns `None` so `not None` evaluates to `True`.

```
>>> s = set()
>>> y = s.add(1) # methods usually return None
>>> print s, y
set([1]) None
```

The reason why the code has been written this way is to sneakily take advantage of Python's list comprehension speed optimizations.

Python methods will usually return `None` if they modify the data structure (`pop` is one of the exceptions)

I also noted that the current accepted way of doing this (`2.7+`) which is more readable and doesn't utilize a *hack* is as follows:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> items = [1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2]
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(items))
[1, 2, 0, 3]
```

Dictionary keys must be unique, therefore the duplicates are filtered out.

Comment: does the new method has the same efficiency as the hacky one?

Comment: @user2213606 efficiency, yes, I believe it is not as fast in raw speed though. It's more succinct however

Comment: `list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(items))` is portable to Python3

Comment: @gnibbler good point, for some reason i was under the assumption that it would return a list since it keeps order but this `KeysView` also does

Comment: i tried to test the speed of the function mentioned above, the speed was terribly slow, script can be found here, function was def f12
http://pastebin.com/Q1EXhqsi

Comment: @user2213606 haven't yet looked at the timings but I did say it wouldn't be as fast in raw speed. It is still an O(N) efficient solution though

Answer (score 3):

It is called a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), they provide a syntactically more compact and more efficient way of writing a normal for-loop based solution.

```
def f8(seq): # Dave Kirby
    # Order preserving
    seen = set()
    return [x for x in seq if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)]
```

The above **list comprehension** is roughly equivalent to:

```
def f8(seq):
    seen = set()
    lis =[]
    for x in seq:
        if x not in seen:
            lis.append(x)
            seen.add(x)
    return lis
```

Answer (score 3):

The construct is called a list comprehension 
`[x for x in seq if some_condition]`. In this case the condition is that `x` isn't already in the resulting list. You can't inspect the result of a list comprehension while you are running it, so it keeps track of the items that are in there using a set called `seen`

This condition here is a bit tricky because it relies on a side-effect

```
not in seen and not seen.add(x)
```

`seen.add()` always returns `None`. If the item *is* in seen,

`not in seen` is `False`, so the `and` shortcircuits.

If the item *is not* in seen,

`not in seen` is `True` and `not seen.add(x)` is also `True`, so the item is included, and as a side-effect, it is added to the `seen` set

While, this type of thing can be fun, it's not a particularly clear way to express the intent.

I think the less tricky way is much more readable

```
def f8(seq):
    seen = set()
    result = []
    for x in seq:
        if x not in seen:
            result.append(x)
            seen.add(x)
    return result
```