# TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found

Tags: python

I am getting the following error for below piece of code..can anyone provide inputs on how to fix it?

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def main ():

    with open('gerrit_dependencylist.txt') as f:
        dic = OrderedDict()
        seen = set()
        for line in f:
            #print dic,line
            spl = line.split()
            #print "SPL"
            #print spl
            if len(spl) == 1:
                key = spl[0]
                v = ''
            else:
                print "LINE"
                print line
                key, v = spl[0], spl[1:]        
            for value in v:
                if value in dic and dic[value] == [""]:
                    del dic[value]
            for k1,v1 in dic.iteritems():
                if key in v1:
                    dic[k1].append(v)
                    break
            else:
                dic[key] = [v]

    with open('cherrypick_list.txt', 'w') as f:
        for k,v  in dic.items():
            f.write("{} {}\n".format(k," ".join(v)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

INPUT:-

```
KEY    VALUES
353311
344670 
332807 353314
338169 334478
334478 123456 34567
123456 98670
34567  11111  
353314 353311
348521 350166 350168 350169 350170 
350166 348521
350168 348521
350169 348521
350170 348521

CURRENT OUTPUT:-

344670 
332807 3 5 3 3 1 4 3 5 3 3 1 1
338169 3 3 4 4 7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 9 8 6 7 0 1 1 1 1 1
348521 3 5 0 1 6 6 3 5 0 1 6 8 3 5 0 1 6 9 3 5 0 1 7 0 3 4 8 5 2 1 3 4 8 5 2 1 3 4 8 5 2 1 3 4 8 5 2 1
EXPECTED OUTPUT
344670
332807 353314 353311
338169 334478 123456 34567 98670 11111
348521 350166 350168 350169 350170
```

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tesst.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "tesst.py", line 31, in main
    f.write("{} {}\n".format(k," ".join(v)))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found
```

Comment: It means `v` is a list of lists; it should be a list of strings instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Except one case(`344670 ['']`) the value of `v` is always a list of lists, so you need to use a nested list comprehension to flatten the list first.

```
with open('cherrypick_list.txt', 'w') as f:
    for k,v  in dic.items():
        val = [item if isinstance(item, str) else " ".join(item) for item in v ]
        f.write("{} {}\n".format(k,val))
```

Get unique items:

```
val = [item if isinstance(item, str) else " ".join(item) for item in v ]
seen = set()
val = [x for x in val if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)]
```

Comment: The problem is that the data is *mixed*. Sometimes `v` is a list of strings, sometimes it contains *other* lists with strings. You'll produce output with single characters separated with spaces in the other cases.

Comment: @MartijnPieters except one case(`344670 ['']`), it is always a list of lists.

Comment: For *this sample* it may be.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - I incorporated your changes..output looks correct apart from that there is a space between every digit for the values.i updated the question with the current output..

Comment: @user2125827 I checked my code again and it seems to work fine on my system.

Comment: @user2125827 try this : `val = [item if isinstance(item, str) else " ".join(item) for item in v ]` and then use `" ".join(val)` inside format.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - Values are getting printed as a list like 332807 ['353314', '353311']...i want it like 332807 353314 353311..how can this be done?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - thanks ,that worked..but I see one problem ..one of the lines in the output is 348521 350166 350168 350169 350170 348521 348521 348521 348521 ....how can I remove these  unwanted duplicates in the values...?something like while extending..if its already part of key or value,that value should not be extended..

Comment: @user2125827 does the order of items matter?

Comment: @user2125827 I've updated my solution, for explanation of that code, see :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161984/python-list-looping-technique-syntax